# ArcGIS Eclipse PyDev - code autocomplete not working

Tags: python, eclipse, autocomplete, pydev, arcgis

I have ArcGIS 9.3, Eclipse Indigo with PyDev plugin installed. I am unable to configure PyDev so the autocompletion of arcgis functions will work.

I have added python interpreter and path to arcgis bin folder. I am able to run script, import of arcgiscripting works but autocompletion shows only functions that i already used in code, not all possible functions.

Reading other posts i found that in arcgis 10 there is arcpy folder that should be added to pythonpath, i cant find similar folder in arcgis 9.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a similar folder for ArcGIS 9.3.  ESRI did a major refactor of the Python API when going from 9.3 to 10 and there are many differences, of which this is one.  I found Eclipse very useful for geocoding but I don't recall autocomplete working with ArcGIS 9.3, but I do recall there was an ESRI folder you needed to list in the Eclipse paths though - probably wherever arcgisscript lives.  I also remember having to tweak the PYTHONPATH environment variable. Sorry for being vague but my memory is a bit sketchy because I have long since moved to v10.